# c# class library use files

Tags: c#, file, dll, relative-path, filepath

I'm building a class library which use a `.dat` file, inside the library i made a folder `App_Data` and put the `.dat` file inside it, how can i have my library to use the `.dat` file. How could it be included at the dll when build?

I already tried `Path.GetFullPath`, and almost anything in Path, but all i get is the path to debug folder, and in that folder i dont even have the `.dat` file which i expect to be included because the `.dat` file is in the project.

I just want to use that `.dat` file without hard coding its path, and it should still work when referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must right-click the `.dat` file and set `Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy Always`. Doing so, the path to the debug folder will correctly point to the file. No need to hard code the path.

[image]

If you're interested in embedding the `.dat` file in the `DLL` (a bit more work), you can go this way:

[Can I embed other files in a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890688/114029)

Comment: I see that the entry at your build action is Compile, in mine it's None, should i change it to Compile or leave it that way?

Comment: No need to set `Build Action`... the picture is just to show the property. :)

Comment: Can I also ask how can i reference my class library to other solutions?, What I do is I open the library to my solution and add it to the reference, Is there a better way like copying the DLL, and not the library itself? Since you mention embedding it in the DLL, I would like to do it, but how can i reference just using the DLL and there are two DLLs that are build one in debug and the other at obj folder, which one should i use?

Comment: The correct way is adding the class library project as a reference in any other project that depends on the class library. Manually copying the `DLL` is not recommended.

Comment: And one last thing, is it fine for me to use any of the following Path.GetFullPath or HostingEnvironment.MapPath, or which one should i use? or are there better ways to locate it? thanks

Comment: If `Path.GetFullPath` resolves to the `.dat` correctly, stick to it.