# Embed QuickFIX DataDictionary xml spec file into dll

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, quickfix

I've implemented a FIX client using QuickFIX (quickfixengine.org).  It all works well, but currently I have to ship my .dll alongside the FIX spec xml file FIX42.xml to customers.

I've been able to embed the XML file into a resource file (using Visual Studio), and load it for reading - but I'm not able to reference it back to my SocketInitiator, if it's not physically on the disk.

My fallback option is to dump what's in the resource file on disk, and then set the reference to my temp location in SocketInitiator constructor.

However, this is sort of a workaround, and was wondering if there's a better way of referencing the embedded file directly.

Comment: You also have to ship the QF config file separately no? It looks like resource files are what people use for dll, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890688/can-i-embed-other-files-in-a-dll)

Comment: @rupweb embedding the XML isn't my question. It's referencing embedded resources in Quickfix c++